# Replace turns value into date

Tags: excel, vba

This is strange problem. I have copied some MS Word tables to Excel, but I have get some unwanted characters in them. In all copied cells I have UNICODE (13) (carriage return) and Unicode(7) (whatever it is) on the end. So, I added line to my VBA code

```
ws.Cells.Replace CharW(13) & CharW(7), ""
```

to remove them. It works fine with one exception: the string "1" & UTF(13) & UTF(7) is changed into date 1899/12/31. I am stucked and I don't want what to do.

Comment: Can you check the format of the cell in question? If the string before replacement is the one as above and cell format is date then it won't show up as date but the moment you replace it shows date. I get 1/1/1900 though.

Comment: this is in the newly created worksheet, but I have set .NumberFormat = "General" and it helped. Thank you very much.